# "command not found" when running "lessc" from bash

Tags: bash, css

I have installed [`lessc`](http://lesscss.org/) via `npm`, Node.js Package Manager, and when I run `lessc` from terminal using

```
lessc /var/www/less/style.less /var/www/css/style.css
```

it works perfectly.
However, when I put this exact same command in a bash script, `less.sh`, it returns the error

> `lessc : command not found.`

Also, I need to run this command from a bash script, because `incron`, a program which I am using to re-compile my less script each time they are modified, is unable to run the command mentioned above, which I believe may be caused by weird methods for handling white-space in the command.

Comment: The non-working script is run in the same terminal where `lessc` works, or in some other ways (cron, a launcher, Alt-F2, other)?

Comment: There's a backtick at the end of your command. Is this typo only here or is it also in your less.sh?

Comment: yes the backtick was a typo. @enzotib does it matter where the script is being run from, and would it change anything that could cause the error mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, it matters. In different situation you can have different PATHs.

Comment: Thanks, after researching the $PATH variable I found that lessc was in "/opt/lessc/bin/lessc", which needed to be added to $PATH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where is the "lessc" executable? Do:

```
type -p lessc
```

and take note of the directory, and figure out where that directory is added to your PATH. I think that bash and incron do not source your setup files (.bashrc, etc) the same way. Reading the Bash man page, the INVOCATION section describes how bash finds its startup files. A quick grep through the incron source shows that it doesn't mention .bashrc or .bash_profile.

You could change the "lessc" command in your script to:

```
/actual/path/to/lessc
```

that you found via

```
type -p lessc
```

Comment: Or add the "/actual/path/to/lessc/" to $PATH, by using the command "PATH=$PATH:/actual/path/to/lessc/" in the bash file. And thanks for posting that as a answer (not a comment).

Answer (score 20):

```
npm install -g less
```

That installs Less.js globally. Maybe you tried this already but it's not in the documentation on http://lesscss.org/; I had to ask around in #node.js on FreeNode.

Comment: I execute your command in my ubuntu terminal but I got                                       npm ERR! Refusing to delete: /usr/bin/lessc not in /usr/lib/node_modules/less
File exists: /usr/bin/lessc
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-90-generic-pae
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! cwd /home/best
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/lessc
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Answer (score 0):

in lubuntu:

```
$ type -p lessc
$ lessc
El programa «lessc» no está instalado. Puede instalarlo escribiendo:
sudo apt-get install node-less
$ sudo apt-get install node-less
```